# Dockerizing existing application

Tags: docker

I am completely new to docker and i am not a developer. Right now i have an application which runs on `centos/nginx/dotnetcore` . In `dotnet core` i have 4 applications, we run them using `dotnet appname.dll`. or rather `systemd`. If i want to dockerize this application set, should i create `centos` as a separate docker image and then `nginx` as other image and then an image for each of the application ? If yes how do i link them, or should i create only one image with centos/nginx and all 4 applications (which is in tar) installed? Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the dockerfile below about the ASP.NET rest API. It is the same way when you call dotnet appname.dll. Instead of running in Centos it runs in container which is debian based if I'm not wrong

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY MicroService1.csproj MicroService1/
RUN dotnet restore MicroService1/MicroService1.csproj

COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish ./MicroService1.csproj -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1
WORKDIR /app
RUN ls
COPY --from=build-env /app/out ./

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MicroService1.dll"]
```

If you have 4 dependent applications you can use docker-compose.

```
version: '3.0'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     environment:
       MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
       MYSQL_DATABASE: accountowner
       MYSQL_USER: dbuser
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: dbuserpassword
     volumes:
       - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
     ports:
       - "3306:3306"
     restart: always

   microservice1:
     depends_on:
       - db
     build:
       context: ./MicroService1/MicroService1
     ports:
       - "8080:80"
     restart: always

   frontend:
     depends_on:
       - microservice1
     build:
       context: ./Frontend
     ports:
       - "4200:4200"

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

Above docker-compose.yml given. It contains 3 service which are frondend, backend and database. In your docker-compose.yml you should define your 4 application

Comment: Is it straight from dev's build? can i create containers based out of `tar` files that i get these days to install?

Comment: You can skip restore build part and just copy dll's and execute dotnet appname.dll. But it is healthier to build in container

Comment: May i know the reason behind building in container from source code? right now i have only tar files, i.e already built apps, so i can just `ADD` them?

Comment: Let's say you built your application on windows, and trying to run on debian. There might be dependencies which can cause problems but I have not encountered that kind of a problem yet. Yes you can add everything then execute appnet.dll

Answer (score 0):

nginx and dotnet as 2 seperate containers for each application would be ideal and recomended